# Connection attempts on port 80 in router logs but not server logs

Tags: apache2, security, log

I have a static Apache2 website on port 80 on an Ubuntu server connected to my LAN behind a router.  The website functions normally.

My router logs are showing bursts of connection attempts to port 80 like this

```
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:31560 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:30:16
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:25586 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:29:51
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:25216 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:28:38
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:52677 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:28:13
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:36812 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:27:00
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:45750 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:26:36
[LAN access from remote] from 46.101.54.78:17352 to [my.servers.internal.url]:80, Tuesday, Apr 10,2018 12:26:11
```

But these connection attempts don't show up in either the Apache2 error or access logs.

Are there any other logs that might show what's going on here?

Comment: I think the port 80 is redirected from your router to your computer... I think apache only log request and effective error, if this external access just opens the TCP port 80 and do not send data, this will probably be the result.

Comment: I just tried to connect locally to apache (using telnet), no request, no log confirmed.

Comment: You are correct that port 80 is forwarded from the router to the server.  Thanks for the insight. Would this be some kind of scan going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a [SYN flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) attack.

In brief, the remote attacker try to open as many TCP connection as possible, trying to exhaust some resource (memory, log disk, ...).

The default apache2 configuration (as tested on 16.04) does not log such data-less connection.

Your ubuntu box should be protected against that kind of attack, `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` seems to be enable by default on ubuntu, but your router may be at risk.